# Counting occurrences of observations

Tags: r

I have a object with 100 observations (it can be A,B,C or D) and I would like to know of how many times each group (it can be A,B,C or D) appears into this object:

eg.

```
A<-rnorm(100, mean = 0, sd = 1)
B<-rnorm(100, mean = 0, sd = 1)
C<-rnorm(100, mean = 0, sd = 1)
D<-rnorm(100, mean = 0, sd = 1)

the.matrix<-matrix(c(A,B,C,D),ncol=4)
colnames(the.matrix)=c("As","Bs","Cs","Ds") 

rep<-100
aux<-NULL

for (i in 1:rep) {
  aux[i]<-ifelse(max(the.matrix[i,])==the.matrix[i,1],"A", 
          ifelse(max(the.matrix[i,])==the.matrix[i,2],"B", 
          ifelse(max(the.matrix[i,])==the.matrix[i,3],"C", 
          ifelse(max(the.matrix[i,])==the.matrix[i,4],"D", "error"))))
} # if you found a simplest way to collect this information, please share this here
```

Now aux have the 100 observations with different amount of A, B, C and D. I just need to know how many times each letter appear in aux

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another option without the loop is `max.col` to get the index of the column, then use that to replace with the column names and we get the frequency with `table`

```
table(colnames(the.matrix)[max.col(the.matrix)])
#   As Bs Cs Ds  
#  34 20 15 31
```

Based on the OP's code

```
table(aux)
#  aux
#  A  B  C  D 
# 34 20 15 31
```

NOTE: The `seed` was not set for the random number generation.